# What verb form to use for tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

This might seem superfluous, and it's probably already stablished in
the stack exchange community as a whole, but it would be good to
standardise anyway.

When tagging questions, should we use `load` or `loading`? `align` or `aligning`?

Answer (score 3):

Go with the gerund. The intuition for tag names is that they complete the sentence “this question is about ____”. Infinitives are a poor fit.

Looking at existing sites, a tag called `align` exists only on [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), where it's a proper noun and not the verb; `aligning` exists nowhere; `alignment` exists on 10 sites.  A tag called `load` exists on many sites, but it's about the system load (so a noun), not about the verb (at least officially: it does get a lot of misuse, where “load” is used to mean “I happen to be loading something” instead of “this question is about loading something”).

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the `load`/`align` form is more natural. They fit nicely into the thought-phrase "I want to ____ X".

The `-ing` form fits into "I am **_** X", but questions are asked when one *wants* to do (or know how to do) X, not when one *is* doing X.

Comment: Does anyone know the grammatical terms for each of these forms?

Comment: I think that's simple present `load` and present participle (imperfect) `loading`

Answer (score -1):

I would go with `load`/`align` for verb tags.

Treat it as an imperative.  You are trying to tell Emacs to `verb`.  To go with what J David Smith said, `-ing` is what you are looking to do, while you are looking for the method to get Emacs to do what you want.

This also matches Emacs convention on commands for the most part.  `fill-*`, `align-*`, `comment-*`, `*-get-*`.